# Corrupted characters posted to PHP via HTML form

Tags: php, html, encoding, utf-8

I know this must be a relatively simple problem, but Google has failed me. Say I have the following simple PHP document (no discussion on security, SQL injection, XSS, etc. This is just a simple example to illustrate my encoding problem):

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['message'])) {
    file_put_contents($filename, $_POST['message']);
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/></head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="?">
    <textarea name="message">
    <?php echo htmlentities(file_get_contents($filename))?>
    </textarea>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, I enter a **Σ** into the form and submit. When the page reloads, the textarea is filled with **Î£** instead of **Σ**.

I understand why this is (to a degree), but I do not know how to fix the post to stop it from happening. Any ideas?

Comment: Is your database saved in UTF-8?

Comment: No database. Files. Although I am sure the same would happen if I saved to database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`htmlentities`](http://www.php.net/htmlentities) defaults to assuming ISO-8859-1 as input, but you feed it utf-8..., so a correct way would be `htmlentities($string, ENT_COMPAT,"UTF-8");`

In this case I'd rather go for `htmlspecialchars` though, other entities shouldn't be needed.

Comment: Did not realize `htmlentities` worked that way. With `htmlspecialchars` it works like a charm, and is the proper function to call given what I was using it for. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I see that you are adding text to a file and then pulling that file back out. Did you try using `utf8_encode()` when adding the information to the file.

```
 file_put_contents($filename, utf8_encode($_POST['message']));
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that gave me **Ã�Â£**

Comment: Did you try removing the `htmlentities()`?

Comment: Funny thing is... `utf8_decode` would work... But better tell `htmlentities` you have an actual utf8-string... My rule of thumb usually is: if you serve utf-8, and you have `utf8_encode` or `utf8_decode` anywhere in your code, something is actually wrong.